# Different result between CPU and GPU(CUDA) in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I build OpenCV 3.0.0 by myself with VS 2013.

I applied fastNlMeansDenoising(both CPU version and CUDA version) on the same image with the same parameter,
But the result is DIFFERENT !!

what's going on??

I guess the reason is the precision of CPU and GPU is different.

```
   #include <string>
   #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/photo/cuda.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/photo.hpp>

   using namespace std;
   using namespace cv;

   int main(){

       string imageName("input.bmp");

       //CPU version
       Mat image = imread(imageName.c_str(), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
       Mat reslutCPU;
       fastNlMeansDenoising(image, reslutCPU, 2.5, 7, 31);
       imwrite("cpu.bmp", reslutCPU);

       //CUDA version       
       cuda::GpuMat imageGPU;
       cuda::GpuMat reslutGPU;
       Mat buff;
       imageGPU.upload(image);
       cuda::fastNlMeansDenoising(imageGPU, reslutGPU, 2.5, 7, 31);
       reslutGPU.download(buff);
       imwrite("gpu.bmp", buff);

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Your code seems good and should provide the same result.

What is the magnitude order of the difference ? More than 1 gray level or not ? If this is more than 1, it could be a problem in opencv library, you can fill a bug report here : http://opencv.org/support.html

Comment: Thank you!
But, I'm not sure What do you mean,
below is my result:

1.INPUT: http://i.imgur.com/S3JBBxl.png
2.CPU: http://i.imgur.com/vHDgeN7.png
3.GPU: http://i.imgur.com/wkLPhn2.png

I think this is a bug.

Comment: Have you tried by using prebuilt library?

Comment: prebuilt dosen't has CUDA.

Comment: there is up to 4 gray level of difference between your GPU and CPU computations it is too much for a rounding error. We can note that results are identical for all white areas in your images. I've not seen opencv code, but do you have the same difference using a simple filter like "gaussian blur" on GPU ? Are opencv coder using textures to apply filter and forgot to use +0.5 on pixels to texels coordinates ?